# How to get syntax highlighting for both HTML and React.js code in Sublime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

There are numerous questions about how to get syntax highlighting in sublime for react. But my question is a bit different. I'm trying to get react syntax highlighting **when it's in an html file** so both the html code and the js code is syntax highlighted. is this possible? From what I'm seen so far you can do either/or but not both.

If install react/babel, and I choose "view->syntax->babel->javascript" then it seems to do syntax highlighting but then my HTML syntax highlighting gets messed up (in my .html file). See "html comment" in the code below, how it's not syntax highlighted...

[image]

Comment: did you try to change the default view of your html file , from html to react-babel ?

Comment: yeah that's what I did, when I change it from html to babel/js then it messes up the html. if it's set to html then my html is fine but then my react code is all white.